# How does the fargte lifecycle handle multiple requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

We have a lambda that will fire requests to another system and I am thinking about using Fargate for this system. What I want to know is whether Fargate will spin up with every request sent to it(like a lambda), or whether it will spin up once and stay alive to handle subsequent requests from the lambda.

Each lambda invocation will only fire one request to the Fargate system.

There will be many requests, but will be dormant during night times. How does Fargate handle spinning up and down between requests?

Comment: fargate will not spin up anything unless you tell it to, you would need to configure autoscaling for this. and generally now, it will not and you should not spin up a new instance per request, unless your requests uses an entire instance for a long time. If that is not the case one running instance can and will handle multiple requests.

Comment: Ah I see, I think I misunderstood the fargate concept and got it muddled up with how a lambda a invoked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've found extended answer in the article [Concurrency Compared: AWS Lambda, AWS App Runner, and AWS Fargate](https://nathanpeck.com/concurrency-compared-lambda-fargate-app-runner/):

> AWS Fargate is similar to AWS App Runner in that each container can serve many concurrent requests.

> This means that if your load balancer receives a large spike of traffic then the requests will be distributed across all the available containers.

> However, it is up to you to use the metrics to define your own scaling rules. You can create scaling rules based on metrics that ECS captures, such as application CPU or memory consumption. Or you can create scaling rules based on metrics from the load balancer, such as concurrent requests or request latency. You can even create custom scaling metrics powered by your application itself. This gives you maximum control over the scaling and concurrency of your application.